# Why my Rcmdr language is in Spanish, while my R (and windows) is in Portuguese? How to solve it?

Tags: r

I teach statistics to undergrads in Brazil. This semester I asked students to install R (version 4.0.2) and the package Rcmdr, since it is a very good free alternative to do statistics, without having to learn how to code in R.
However, all of my students, and myself, found that Rcmdr opens in Spanish, not Portuguese. The R itself, RGui, opens in Portuguese.
I managed to open Rcmdr in English if, before loading Rcmdr, I set the language to english:

```
Sys.setenv(LANG='en')
```

I also managed to solve it by changing the desktop shortcut, adding LANG='EN' at the end of the command. I know it is also possible if you change the "Rconsole" file.

But I want/need to know:

Is there an easier solution? I need to share a solution with students, and the simpler the better.

How to set the language to portuguese? (already tried 'pt', 'ptbr', 'portuguese', no success)

Why is this happening, since Rcmdr have a Portuguese translation?

Comment: It seems like a bug that could be easily fixed. You should report it to the Rcmdr team here: https://github.com/cran/Rcmdr/issues

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I didn't think of that. I'll do it right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I talked to the package developers, and the error was due to a misplaced file. Should be corrected soon.
Also, I learn the correct command to change the language to Brazilian Portuguese:

```
Sys.setenv(LANG='pt_BR')
```